# Pandas fill NaN base on last available value and the next available value

Tags: python, pandas

I have csv data looks like this:

```
     A     B
0   x aa   
1   z aa   
2          
3   
4   x aa   
5   z bb
6   x bb
7          
8   z cc
```

I would like to fill the empty cells in B column with values in A, if in A column

```
last_available_value_before_the_NaNs_in_A.split()[-1] == next_available_value_after_the_NaNs_in_A.split()[-1]
```

the wanted result would be:

```
     A     B
0   x aa   aa 
1   z aa   aa
2          aa
3          aa
4   x aa   aa
5   z bb   bb
6   x bb   bb
7          
8   z cc   cc
```

`data.loc(7,'B')` will be NaN because `data.loc(6,'A').split()[-1] == 
data.loc(8,'A').split()[-1]` is false.

`data.loc(5,'B')` is 'bb' because `data.loc(5,'A').split()[-1] == 'bb'`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why does `data.loc[5, 'B']` get filled then? `data.loc[4, 'A'].split()[-1] != data.loc[5, 'A'].split()[-1]`. Also could you be more precise what actually `last_available_value` and `next_available_value` denote?

Comment: Hi guest,because data in [5, 'A'] is given.

Comment: Hi I'm talking about last available value before the NaNs ( and next available value after NaNs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could compare a version that uses `ffill` and one that uses `bfill`:

```
f = df.A.fillna(method='ffill').str.split().str[-1]
b = df.A.fillna(method='bfill').str.split().str[-1]
df.B.where(f != b, f, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Your's is much more compact than mine. like it

Answer (score 0):

This is verbose to illustrate the idea.

```
# create a column that jsut holds the last value
df["lastval"] = df.A.str.split().str[-1]
# fill blanks in a feed-forward manner
df["ffill"] = df.lastval.fillna(method="ffill") 
# fill blanks in a feed-backward manner
df["bfill"] = df.lastval.fillna(method="bfill") 

# create a mask that handles your logic
m = df.lastval.isnull() & (df["ffill"] == df["bfill"])   
# fill those values into B from lastval
df["B"] = df["lastval"]
df.loc[m,"B"] = df.loc[m, "ffill"]
```